# Transform Angular 2 Observable Into a non observable

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am using 6.3 of NGX Data Table which cannot bind to an observable collection.  How do I transform an Angular Observable Collection into a regular non-observable Array?

**Here is what I have for the service:**

```
private _productUrl = '../../api/todos/todos.json';

constructor(private _http: Http) { }

getToDos(): Observable<IToDo[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IToDo[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**Here is what I have for the component.ts.  It gives me an error on the foreach loop: *Cannot read property 'length' of undefined***

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._toDoService.getToDos()
        .subscribe(
          toDos => this.toDos = toDos,
          error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

    this.rows = this.transform(this.toDos);
}

transform(source: IToDo[]): IToDo[] {
    let dest: IToDo[] = [];

    for (let sourceItem of source)
    {
      let destItem: IToDo = {
        toDoId: sourceItem.toDoId,
        name: sourceItem.name,
        priority: sourceItem.priority,
        dueDate: sourceItem.dueDate,
        completed: sourceItem.completed
      };
      dest.push(destItem);
    }

    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observables can be asynchronous, so you cant simply manipulate todos right after the subscription call you make. Instead, manipulate todos inside of the subscription:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._toDoService.getToDos()
    .subscribe(
      toDos => {
        this.toDos = toDos
        this.rows = this.transform(this.toDos);
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Your this.transform call was being called synchronously, meaning your call stack is just a linear progression of calls.

Comment: Observables **can** be asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

You can also unwrap the input Observable using the [async](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html) pipe.

```
 <ngx-datatable
        class="material"
        [rows]="todos | async"
        ......
 </ngx-datatable>
```

Comment: David, thanks for the kind suggestion.  I tried that first but for some reason it did not work with the binding.  https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/373